# Use Query to change status of an entry

Tags: query

THE SHORT: I am looking for the sql query I need to run in order to change the status of an entry. Any help would be appreciated.

THE LONG: I have two sperate channels and they are NOT linked via a relationship field, however if the status of an entry in Channel A is closed and a field in Channel A matches a field in Channel B I need to update the status of the entry in Channel B.  I plan on running this via a cron to automatically update these entries and I dont want to require my users manually change the entries.

Thanks.

Comment: If there isn't a relationship field, how do you know which entry in Channel B to compare to the entry in Channel A?

Comment: The field is generated from an existing field from a different channel using stash. It's wonky - but works for what i needed without creating a relationship field.

Comment: A trigger is more elegant in this case than a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks for a query to change the status of an entry. This is the code you'd use to change the status for a specific entry_id:

```
 UPDATE exp_channel_titles t 
 SET t.status = 'pending' 
 WHERE t.status = 'open'
 AND t.entry_id = "1"
```

I suspect you need something more complicated though. If that's the case, you'll need to update your questions with more specific detail.